# BlackBerry stop receiving push notifications

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

I have signed with RIM for BlackBerry Push Service Evaluation Credentials so that i can test my push notifications implementation.

I used the low level sample as my server to send the push and i build the client side.
Everything worked well till now. Suddenly my application stopped showing the received push messages. Instead every time i send a push i can see in the right up corner an arrow loading (like something is being processed) but no push notification is shown.

Is really strange , cause i didnt do any change on my code.. Any ideas?

### EDIT

---

Actually i found out that when i deploy the app in the device , the push doesnt work as i described. When i restart the phone though , the push works fine. I think maybe is because , i call the background process for listening for push , when the phone gets restarted. Have a look on my code: http://codepad.org/ddJvyOox

When i launch the app , i register to BIS for push but i think i dont listen for them. I do that every time the phone restarts.. Do you think this might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Curious are you behind a firewall by any chance?

To consider adding firewall exceptions to have access for the eval/prod PPG then need to add the IP addresses below:

**Eval:**

68.171.224.57

68.171.224.59

**Production:**

74.82.67.65

74.82.67.66

74.82.67.70

74.82.71.70

---

Another high level check before diving deeper; are you able to login into the [EVAL CP Portal URL](https://cpadmin.pushapi.eval.blackberry.com/mss/CP_login) Your credentials might have been reset/expired, if so contacting blackberrypushservices@rim.com to help with access to the portal.

---

On the application level, the app needs to connect to the InvokeManager signal at the beginning.

onInvoked() function would first check to see the bb::network::PushService instance exists and the appID is stored.

```
connect(m_invokeManager, SIGNAL(invoked(const bb::system::InvokeRequest&)),
    SLOT(onInvoked(const bb::system::InvokeRequest&)));
```

The application will extract the push message from the invoke request by passing the invoke request into the PushPayload constructor if the action property  of InvokeRequest matches the string constant BB_PUSH_INVOCATION_ACTION from the onInvoked() function.

---

Do any of these suggestions work?  Otherwise please explain more in depth which client/server code you have implemented and the bar-descriptor file's properties.

Curious to know where are you located as there might be the likelihood of Push Service outage if Push Notifications suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Thank you very mych for trying to help , really appreciate it. Please check my edited answer. I found out , something that might be helpful.